# Web service software factory 2008 Modelling edition Generate Code button no Enabled

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2008, service-factory

I installed following softwares to enable WCF modeling projects in Visual Studio 2008 SP1. But one option 'Generate Code' is not visible for WCF Contract diagrams.

1) Web service software factory Modelling edition 2008
2) Guidance Automation Extensions 2008

Please let me know if you have any suggestions in this regard.

Thanks,
 P V.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem repeatedly.
Sometimes the guidance package gets disabled.
In Visual Studio 2008, go to `Tools -> Guidance Package Manager -> Enable / Disable Packages`.  Tick the box at `Service Factory: Modeling Edition` and confirm.

That should fix the problem.